# How to export ddl for hbase table

Tags: hbase, ddl

how can we export a ddl for a hbase table ? I would like to export the ddl and use it on another environment to recreate the table . 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a snapshot

> hbase shell

```
hbase> snapshot 'myTable', 'myTableSnapshot-122112'
```

2. Make sure it is listed.

> hbase> list_snapshots

3. Export the snapshot to other cluster.execute below command in terminal

> hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot -snapshot
>    -copy-from
>   hdfs://{from_cluster_namenode:port}/hbase/data/ -copy-to
>   hdfs://{to_cluster_namenode:port}/hbase/data/ -mappers 16
>
> This will trigger a MR job to transfer the snapshot.

4. login to other cluster, make sure the the snapshot is transferred to new cluster.

> ```
> hbase> hbase shell
>
> hbase> list_snapshots
> ```

5. restore the snapshot in the new cluster. below command in the hbase shell.

> hbase> restore_snapshot 'snapshotName'

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding of your requirement, you are looking for something similar to RBDMS (say, oracle) is providing.

If that is the case, Exporting table structure alone doesn’t make much sense
in HBase case as HBase table can contain unstructured data.
I mean, number of column qualifiers (Equivalent with Oracle columns) is not
fixed.

If you want to create table with given column families and other parameters like replication factor etc you can use below command in hbase shell.

`describe TABLE_NAME`

This will provide you required information, from which you can create tables on any hbase instance with given column families etc.